# How to update child component with resolved promise value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stuck with an architecture that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, top level `Component 1` defines functions and data that are passed as props to the `Component 2` and then later also as props to `Component 3`, where the data is rendered, and the functions are invoked.

This worked fine so far, but now the issue is that `Component 1` has introduced a call to an async function that returns a promise, which when resolved updates the original data later passed as props to `Component 2`, but `Component 3` is never informed that data has been updated, and because of that it never re-renders and never shows updated data.

As I am not allowed to change this failing architecture, I need an advice on how to re-render `Component 3` when `Component 1` updates original props ?

Comment: This is perfectly normal. When Component 1 gets the updated data (e.g., new state), it should re-render, which will pass the updated data to Component 2 and thus to Component 3. Am I missing a subtlety somewhere? If so, a [mcve] demonstrating the problem would probably help, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I might come up with an example later, but basically, after promise is resolved, component 3 doesn't re-renders with the updated data automatically, this only happens when I manually initiate re-render of the component by making an additional action...

Comment: It sounds like Component 1 doesn't treat that information as state. Since it is state, it should treat it as state. That will trigger the render automatically.

Comment: Well I have just found out with React Dev Tools, that the state has changed, and that each component (component3, component2 and component 1) all have the updated value, but this didn't trigger re-render....

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  What Component 1 actually does is, it populates an `object` with data and dispatches that data to an action. That part is fine. The issue is, at about the same time it also wait for promise to be resolved in order to update the original `object` that was dispatched a bit earlier. So `object` is updated, the state of the `Component 1` is updated, but React is not aware of it and it doesn't re-render the component, If I click manually on the component to initiate re-render, the data shown is fine..

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is the way that Props are passed down from First to third component, check this basic working example:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fromFirst: 0
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
     // Used just as example of async triggering
     setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({fromFirst: 1})
     }, 2000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      Hello {this.props.name}
      <SecondComponent fromFirst={this.state.fromFirst} />
    </div>
    )
 }
}

class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     fromSecond: 2
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div> 
    <p> From First: {this.props.fromFirst} </p>
    <p> On Second: {this.state.fromSecond}</p>
    <ThirdComponent fromFirst={this.props.fromFirst} fromSecond={this.state.fromSecond}/>
    </div>)
  }

}

class ThirdComponent extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     fromThird: 2
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Third asks of first {this.props.fromFirst}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Check working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0zLqgch/1/)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with a passing a value, the value gets passed to the Component 3 but it's now aware of it.  What Component 1 actually does is, it populates an `object` with data and dispatches that data to an action. That part is fine. The issue is, at about the same time it also wait for promise to be resolved in order to update the original `object` that was dispatched a bit earlier. So `object` is updated, the state of the `Component 1` is updated, but React is not aware of it and it doesn't re-renders the component...

Comment: Well, the basic example above works well, based on your description of the problem, without a more thorough example it'll be hard to assess the root problem.

Use it as a basic starting point, and if it helped you please accept the answer, if not, add a JSFiddle with your working example, otherwise it's hard to help you out

Comment: Yeah sure, but I found a solution. Basically when the promise is resolved I am dispatching a new action. This pretty much makes React aware that state has been changed and re-renders the component. Wish it worked without this awful hack...

Comment: @Zed Try importing RXJS for more complex scenarios, you can pass a subscription as props and then subscribe to them in child elements to update their state. 
Otherwise, use Redux

Answer (score 0):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690942/how-to-update-child-component-with-resolved-promise-value?noredirect=1#comment92313057_52690942) you've said:

> What Component 1 actually does is, it populates an object with data and dispatches that data to an action. ... at about the same time it also wait for promise to be resolved in order to update the original object that was dispatched a bit earlier...

That's the problem. You cannot modify state or props directly; [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). That means you cannot assign to properties on `this.state` **or properties on objects it refers to**. Instead, you have to replace them with new objects. E.g., you can't do this:

```
// WRONG
this.state.foo.bar = 42;
```

Instead, you have to do this:

```
this.setState(({foo}) => ({foo: {...foo, bar: 42}}));
```